# How to install sqlite SQLite 3.7.11 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, database, backport, sqlite

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24699828/249341), to get code my code work on this 12.04 machine I need to upgrade the version of SQLite to 3.7.11. However, on Ubuntu 12.04 the installed version of sqlite is

```
> sqlite3 --version
3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e
```

How do I upgrade SQLite (I'm stuck using 12.04)? If the answer is, "use this magic PPA", please tell me how you found it - I tried searching and left empty-handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.7.11 is from an unsupported release. Look at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3 and you can see 3.8.5-2ubuntu1 is the latest and you can download it from there and install it with software center.

- [3.8.5 can be downloaded from the sqlite.org website](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).